# Is it fine to say that something is a "good listen " or a "good watch" similar to the occasions we one says some written thing being a good read?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I am wondering if it's idiomatic to describe something as "good listen" and "good watch"? For example,

- That song, the other night you introduced me to, was a good listen.
- The movie 1917 was a good watch, I recommend that you watch it.

Answer (score 3):

I am familiar with the idiom "a good read". I have never heard either "a good watch" or "a good listen". They would be understandable, but to me aren't idiomatic.